# Python Program that loops until the user says No, then will sum all transactions and dollar amount

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I'm very new to python. Need to get this working.

The program asks user how many tickets they want, after they input they get that ticket amount and transaction amount (tickets are 5 dollars). so far so good. Program works as is supposed to.
Program then asks user if they want to continue, if they say yes, program will start over. If they say no, program will then sum all transactions and output results of number of tickets purchased and dollar amount.
That's where I get stuck. How do I get the program to loop and output the sum of all amounts?
I know I should be adding them to some kind of list that will sum. But how do I do this? :(

```
tickets = input("How many tickets would you like? ")
tickets = int(tickets)
totalTicket = (tickets * 5)

print(f"You ordered {tickets} tickets and your total is {totalTicket} Dollars")

continuePurchase = input("Would you like to continue? Y/N \n")

while True:
    if continuePurchase == "Y":
        tickets = input("How many tickets would you like? ")
        tickets = int(tickets)
        totalTicket = (tickets * 5)

        print(
            f"You ordered {tickets} tickets and your total is {totalTicket} Dollars")
        continue
    elif continuePurchase == "N":
```

Comment: You should probably be adding the number of tickets being purchased to a list. Currently tickets is getting rewritten every time the loop is running. Then when they answer no, loop through the array.

Comment: You can `break` out of the while loop or change `while True:` to `while continuePurchase != "N":`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you always set the total tickets from the most recent user input, you are not going to be able to get the total tickets from more than one user inputs. You need to add items to a list. It can be any size and you can add new elements to it (in our case, new tickets being purchased)

It is also wise to avoid loops that use {while true}. Since we always want to loop when the user input is Y, then that can be the condition of the loop. Loop until the user input is not Y (I would add a function to make sure the user is entering Y or N. If they do not, ask the question again)

```
continuePurchase = "Y"
purchaseList = []

'TODO I would check if there is a valid input. Is it y/n? Should the upper/lower case matter'
while continuePurchase == "Y": 
    tickets = input("How many tickets would you like?")
    purchaseList.append(int(tickets))
    totalTicket = (tickets * 5)

    print(f"You ordered {tickets} tickets and your total is {totalTicket} Dollars")

    continuePurchase = input("Would you like to continue? Y/N \n")

'Answer was N, so now we can add up all the tickets'
print("You have purchased ", sum(purchaseList), " tickets total")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, this is a slightly modified code of yours. This works:

```
tickets = input("How many tickets would you like? ")
tickets = int(tickets)
totalTicket = (tickets * 5)

while True:
    continuePurchase = input("Would you like to continue? Y/N \n").lower()
    if continuePurchase == "y":
        tickets = input("How many tickets would you like? ")
        tickets = int(tickets)
        totalTicket = (tickets * 5)
        continue
    else:
        break
print(f"You ordered {tickets} tickets and your total is {totalTicket} Dollars")
```